# Multiple Read statements. Do not proceed until user input is given

Tags: bash, shell

I have a few read statements. Im trying to figure out how to prevent the user from going to the next statement unless they have provided user input. I am having trouble wrapping my head around this. I have seen examples for a single read -p statement but can't seem to find an appropriate solution for multiple subsequent read statements.

```
     read -p " Write something: " var1
     read -p " Write something again: " var2
     read -p " write something a third time: " var3
```

```
 desired output
 Write something: #no input
 You have not entered anything. Please try again.
 Write something: computer
 Write something again
```

then proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as Cyrus posted but with a warning

```
until [[ "$var1" ]]; do
    read -p " Write something: " var1
    [[ "$var1" ]] || echo "You have not entered anything. Please try again."
done
```

And this will create all vars in one loop

```
vars=(var1 var2 var3)

for varname in ${vars[@]}; {
    until [[ "${!varname}" ]]; do
        read -p " Write something to $varname: " $varname
        [[ "${!varname}" ]] || echo "You have not entered anything. Please try again."
    done    
}
```

We can go further and use an array to store data

```
for i in {1..3}; {
    until [[ "${vars[$i]}" ]]; do
        read -p "Write something to var$i: " vars[$i]
        [[ "${vars[$i]}" ]] || echo "You have not entered anything. Please try again."
    done    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I find that this does work well for single read statements. However, the minute I add more than one read -p statement within the do/done. It will iterate through and still go to the next read statement even though i did not enter any input. (it does show the warning after every statement when there is no input provided.) Perhaps I am not understanding this correctly.

Comment: Hey @Ivan i overlooked " Write something to $varname: " $varname. Which is crucial. I really appreciate your response. Using this method saved many lines of code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while [[ "$var1" = "" ]]; do read -p " Write something: " var1; done
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. This was the route I was initially going with. I outlined my issue in Cyrus' reply.

Comment: `while [[ ! $var ]]` should be enough.