# Most efficient way to perform exception handling in bash?

Tags: bash, performance, validation, exception, input

I'm new to bash scripting & more familiar with python, but lets say I have this script for example.

**Problem:** 
*Entire script terminates if null value is inputed, such as accidental pressing enter twice or not putting "n" or "y" when prompted.*

**Solution Goal:** 
*Instead of terminating, I would like to add exception/error message & perform prompt the user again every time there's a null value or a not an y/n.*

```
read -r -p "Check the test results below.. do they look good enough to continue? [y/N]" response 
if pp $response =~ ^([yY[eE][sS]|[yY])$
then
  echo "Continuing"
elif [[ $response =~ ^([nN][oO]|[nN])$ ]]
  exit
else
  # want to use read -r -p prompt again. Perform recursion if possible 
  exit
fi
```

I am trying to perform recursion with this builtin type read. I am wondering if there's a simple solution to achieve my goal.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60390331/3776858) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose it inside a `while loop`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r -p "Check the test results below.. do they look good enough to continue? [y/N] " response; do
    if [[ $response =~ ^([yY[eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
      echo "Continuing"
    elif [[ $response =~ ^([nN][oO]|[nN])$ ]]; then
      exit
    else
       printf '%s\n' "Illegal argument ${response:-empty}" >&2
    fi
 done
```

- the while read loop should be enough.
- The `"${response:-empty}"` is form of P.E. parameter expansion.